# Is possible to pass 2 variables arguments in a function/method

Tags: ruby

I was trying to do something like this but i don't know much about this language:

`def teste (*array1, *array2)`

Is this possible to do? I have to pass one array of numbers and strings and one only of strings but i dont know how much elements each one has.

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted more of your code.

Comment: @Richard He wants 2 variable length argument lists automatically handled by the language. Something like `teste(var1, var2, var3, var4)` where var1 and var2 are part of array1 and var3 and var4 are part of array2. As I said in my answer, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many elements both of your array arguments have. For your purpose you can do just this:

`def teste(arr_of_strings_and_numbers, arr_of_only_strings)`

Now call the method like this:

`teste( [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] )`

In your method body you have now access to:
`arr_of_strings_and_numbers` which equals `[1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'bar']`
and
`arr_of_only_strings` which equals `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as many arguments as you need to.

You may not want to "splat"them, though, that does something pretty specific.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, there's no way for the language to know to which array an element belongs to. However you can simply pass 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two variadic lists of arguments in a method. If it were legal to define a method with two variadic lists of arguments like you want to, how would ruby know which argument should go in which array when you call say `teste(a,b,c)`? Should this result in `array1 = [a]; array2 = [b,c]` or `array1 = [a,b]; array2=[c]`? It's impossible to say.

If you want to pass two arrays to a method, just define it to take two regular arguments and then call it with two arrays.